# Aliasing in Java with Arrays and Reference Types

Tags: java, variable-assignment, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

There are many similar question on SO about this, but I haven't been able to find an answer that clearly lists the differences in aliasing, so I am asking here.

I know that a simple primitive assignment statement copies values:

```
int x = 1;
int y = x;
x = 2;
StdOut.print(x); // prints 2
StdOut.print(y); // prints 1
```

Then I was told that arrays are 'aliased' during assignment statements. So:

```
int[] x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int[] y = x;
x[0] = 6;
StdOut.print(x[0]); // prints 6
StdOut.print(y[0]); // prints 6
```

However, if you assign one of the variables a completely different array, this aliasing 'disappears':

```
int[] x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int[] y = x;
x = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
x[0] = 6;
StdOut.print(x[0]); // prints 1
StdOut.print(y[0]); // prints 6
```

What is the reason for this?

Then, I come to reference types. When using assignment statements, it is the reference which is copied, not the value. So:

```
Counter c1 = new Counter("ones");
Counter c1.incrememnt(); // 0 -> 1
Counter c2 = c1;
c2.increment();
StdOut.print(c1); // prints 2
StdOut.print(c2); // prints 2
```

But what about if I then assign `c1` to a new `Counter` object? What happens to `c2`; does it reference the original `Counter` or the new `Counter`, why?

I ask because I originally thought that reference types worked like arrays. If I create a new `Counter` and assign it to `c1`, then both `c1` and `c2` point to the newly created `Counter`. However, after going through some exercises, I created an iterable `Stack` ADT which seems to violate this assumption. My code is below:

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class MyStack<Item> implements Iterable<Item> {

    private Node first; // top of stack
    private int N; // number of items

    private class Node {
        Item item;
        Node next;
    }

    public MyStack() {}

    public Iterator<Item> iterator() {
        return new ListIterator();
    }

    private class ListIterator implements Iterator<Item> {

        private Node current = first;

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return current != null;
        }

        public Item next() {
            Item item = current.item;
            current = current.next;
            return item;
        }

    }

    public void push(Item item) {
        Node oldfirst = first;
        first = new Node();
        first.item = item;
        first.next = oldfirst;
        N++;
    }

    public Item pop() {
        if(!isEmpty()) {
            Node oldfirst = first;
            first = first.next;
            return oldfirst.item;
        } else throw new RuntimeException("Stack underflow");
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() { return size() == 0; }

    public int size() { return N; }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyStack<Integer> stack = new MyStack<>();
        stack.push(5);
        stack.push(6);
        stack.push(7);
        stack.push(8);
        stack.push(9);
        for(int i : stack) {
            StdOut.println(i);
        }
    }

}
```

It's a simple implementation, using a linked list data structure for the items. The main instance variable is `first`, which holds the first node in the linked list (top of the stack). If you look in the nested `ListIterator` class, there's an instance variable `current` which is assigned to `first`. Now, in the `push` method, `first` is reassigned to a newly created `Node`. Surely then the `current` variable is still assigned to the old `first` Node? Why then does this implementation work?

My hunch is that either a) I don't understand how reference values are passed (please explain) or b) when you run through the `for` loop in the main method, it implicitly calls creates a new `ListIterator` which, at that point, assigns `current` to whatever the current value of `first` is. If this is the real reason, then does that mean that a new iterator should be created whenever a method is called within the class? For example, if I create the iterator explicitly, then push a few items to the stack, and then reuse the iterator without re-initialising - will it work as intended?

Please explain!

Comment: Array types **are** reference types. The term _alias_ is not commonly used in Java. You need to make a distinction between a reference, a variable, and an object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is the reason for this?

The variables x and y are not arrays. They are array references. An array is an object, and you reassigned x to refer to a different array than y, and only changed x, thus you have different values in the two different arrays.

> What happens to c2; does it reference the original Counter or the new Counter, why?

In your example there was only one Counter object created, when you called `new Counter`, there's no original, and you made the Counter reference c2 refer to the same instance that c1 refers to, so they are pointing to the same thing.

> Surely then the current variable is still assigned to the old first Node? Why then does this implementation work?

Your for each loop invokes `iterator()` which returns a new `ListIterator` which instantiates it's own `current` which points to the latest value of `first` in your stack.

Comment: With the second question, I think @Keir meant that a new Counter is created after the given code block and assigned to c1. That is, append the given code example with the line `c1 = new Counter("two");`
In that case, c2 will still refer to the "ones" Counter but c1 will refer to the "two" Counter. The object referred to by c2 does not change since there was no additional assignment to c2.

Answer (score 1):

One of my concerns about the way introductory Java tends to be taught is that often aliasing hardly gets mentioned.  It is key to understanding Java to realise what it means, and therefore in my view should be a MAJOR aspect of introductory Java courses.  So often I find students who think they know Java getting completely stuck later on because they were never properly taught it.

It really isn't difficult, all you have to know is that if v1 and v2 are two variables of an object type, the assignment v2=v1 means "v2 stops referring to what it used to refer to and starts referring to what v1 refers to".

So, if you have another variables of an object type v3, and after doing v2=v1 you do v1=v3 it means "v1 stops referring to what it used to refer to, and starts referring to what v3 refers to".  It doesn't mean v2 also stops referring to what v1 used to refer to.  Your misunderstanding comes down to thinking it does.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the reason for this?

```
int[] x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int[] y = x;
x[0] = 6;
StdOut.print(x[0]); // prints 6
StdOut.print(y[0]); // prints 6
```

**x and y** are both **references** that point to one object (an array is an object), so changing the state through any of the references will make changes to the actual object, then both **the references** will reflect the change.

```
x[0] = 6; // then y[0] = 6, too.
```

> However, if you assign one of the variables a completely different array, this aliasing 'disappears':

```
int[] x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int[] y = x;
x = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
x[0] = 6;
StdOut.print(x[0]); // prints 6
StdOut.print(y[0]); // prints 1
```

> Because:

When you point x to another object

```
x = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

y will still point to the original object. Remember that x and y are **just references** which point to objects.

```
int[] x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int[] y = x;
```

So, when we set

```
x[0] = 6;
```

y[0] wasn’t effected.

```
StdOut.print(x[0]); // prints 6
StdOut.print(y[0]); // prints 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Other people have explained well about the principles. I'll apply the rules to explain the behavior of your stack object.

So when you push a node, the 'first' refers to the new, real first node. (Because you created a new Node object and assigned 'first' to that new Node.)

Therefore, the 'current' which refers to 'first', also now refers to the real new first node, not the 'old first node'. That is why it works.

Similarly, when pop method is executed, 'first' now refers to next node of 'oldfirst'. Therefore first now refers to the new first node, which is basically old second node. So it works.

I see why you were confused that 'current' would point to 'old first' regardless of push and pop operations.
Assuming the stack is created only once, 'current = first' operation is executed only once. And there is no other assignment to 'current' happening anywhere else. So we can say current is just another name of 'first' as long as it doesn't get re-assigned to something else. All it does is basically aliasing. It doesn't retain original value of 'first'. It always points to whatever the most recently updated version of 'first' is.